# Probability of getting same configuration in 2 throws with R dices

Tags: probability, combinatorics

EDIT: There's same question already: [Probability of throwing the same multiset twice in a row with six dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125490/probability-of-throwing-the-same-multiset-twice-in-a-row-with-six-dice)

I'm trying to find general solution for a problem from Feller's [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471257087) (p. 56):

> 18. What is the probability that two throws with three dice each will show
>       the same configuration if (a) the dice are distinguishable, (b) they are not?

I'm interested in case (b) but not only for three dices. Sorry if the post is too lengthy. I've tried to summarize my over-complicated reasoning.

Let $N = 6$ be the number of sides on a dice and $r$ be the number of throws. Total number of possible outcomes in a throw with $r$ dices is then $N^r$. I split possible outcomes in $r$ categories. If $i \in {1, ..., r}$ is the number of different sides on dices in an outcome (outcome $[1,1,6]$ means $i=2$), then there's

$$
(N)_{i}{r \brace i}
$$

different outcomes for each $i$. The $(N)_{i}$ is falling factorial and it represents number of choices for $i$ different sides. The ${N \brace i}$ is a Stirling number of second kind and it represents the number of ways to make $i$ non-empty subsets out of a set of size $r$, e.g. for $r=3$, I can throw two sides $1$ and one side $6$ in ${3 \brace 2} = 3$ different ways: $[1,1,6]$, $[1,6,1]$ and $[6,1,1]$. So

$$
\sum_{i=1}^r{(N)_{i}{r \brace i}} = {N^r}.
$$

For two throws there's $N^{2r}$ possible outcomes. I count the number of possible matching outcomes in second throw as the number of ways to divide $r$ dices into $i$ ordered parts (sides). So for $r=3$ the number of matching outcomes in second throw is${3 \choose 3}=1$ for $i=1$, ${3 \choose 2,1}=3$ for $i=2$ and ${3 \choose 1,1,1}=6$ for $i=3$. So for $r=3$ the probability of matching outcome is

$$
p = \frac{(N)_{1}{3 \brace 1} + 3(N)_{2}{3 \brace 2} + 6(N)_{3}{3 \brace 3}}{N^6} = \frac{83}{3888}
$$

which seems to be the correct answer according to solutions in the book but I'm not sure if my reasoning in the second throw is correct and if the result isn't just coincidence, because I can't figure out how to generalize it for any $r$. For instance I can divide $r=5$ dices to $i=3$ sides in $${5 \choose 2,2,1}$$ ways but also in $${5 \choose 3,1,1}$$ ways.

What would be the formula for any $r$ please? Can this problem be interpreted in a simpler way? Thank you.

Comment: do you mean ${r \brace i} = {r \choose i}$?

Comment: @ConradoCosta It's a Stirling number. It's written there o_O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalizing [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/125595) I gave to the other question you linked to for $N\ne r$ yields

$$
\sum_{1n_1+2n_2+\dotso+kn_k=r}\binom{N}{n_1,\ldots,n_k}\left(\frac{r!}{1!^{n_1}\cdots k!^{n_k}}\right)^2
$$

for the explicit version of the number of favourable outcomes and

$$
[x^r]r!^2\left(\sum_{k=0}^r\frac{x^k}{k!^2}\right)^N
$$

for the coefficient version. For your case, $N=6$ and $r=3$, [Wolfram|Alpha gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3!%5E2%20%28sum%20of%20x%5Ek%2Fk!%5E2%20for%20k%3D0..3%29%5E6&dataset=) $996$ for the coefficient (under "Expanded form"). Dividing by $N^{2r}$ then yields the desired probability.

Comment: $996$ is third term of [OEIS A169715](https://oeis.org/A169715) in the same way that in the other question $8848236$ is the sixth term

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question already has the answer in it, As you put it,

$${5 \choose 2,2,1}\neq{5 \choose 3,1,1} $$

And those are the relevant sets, so you need to count them:

$$F =\sum_{i = 1}^r \;\underset{j_1\geq j_2 \geq \ldots \geq j_i}{\sum_{j_1 +\ldots + j_i = r}}{r\choose j_1,j_2 \ldots ,j_i} N (N-1) \ldots (N - i + 1) $$

These are you favorable events. Now to compute the probability, just take
$$ p =\frac{F}{N^{2r}} $$